# Problem storing value in array

Tags: vb.net, exception

I want to store value in array, from my database.  I am using following code but it return error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Code is:

```
Dim w as integer=0

Do While DsChooseSQsNow.tblChooseSQs.Rows.Count > w
      vrSQsNoChosen(w) = DsChooseSQsNow.tblChooseSQs.Rows(w).Item("QNo")
      vrTotalSQsChosen = vrTotalSQsChosen + 1
      w = w + 1
Loop
```

Error comes on `"vrSQsNoChosen(w) = DsChooseSQsNow.tblChooseSQs.Rows(w).Item("QNo")"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many reasons why this code fails. I would start checking from:

- Size (and boundings) of `vrSQsNoChosen` array.
- `w` value when error occurs (is valid index for `vrSQsNoChosen` array and `Rows` collection?).
- `Item("QNo")` value when error occurs (maybe is `null`?).

Also -- VB.NET implements `+=` operator so you can write:

```
  w += 1
```

instead of:

```
 w = w + 1
```

Comment: The problem was with the bound of array.  Solved !  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

try to print the value DsChooseSQsNow.tblChooseSQs.Rows(w).Item("QNo")

or debug the code

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object." means Item("QNo")  may be null

Comment: I printed DsChooseSQsNow.tblChooseSQs.Rows(w).Item("QNo") and value is not Null